# Google Forms batchUpdate to change contentURL of image field - getting spinning wheel

Tags: google-api, google-forms

I have an image field on my Google Form and I'm trying to update the image seen (of an Image field) by the viewer via an batchUpdate API call.

I tried using the code below and got a success response, but when I look at the Form editor window I get the Google spinning wheel of death and if I use preview mode I see no image.

```
{
  "includeFormInResponse": false,
  "requests": [
    {
      "updateItem": {
        "item": {
          "imageItem": {
            "image": {
              "sourceUri": "https://daily.jstor.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/standardizedtests.jpg"
            }
          },
          "itemId": "1df22cd7"
        },
        "location": {
          "index": 0
        },
        "updateMask": "imageItem.image.contentUri"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`I'm trying to update the image seen (of an Image field) by the viewer via an batchUpdate API` You're using the Forms API to update the image value of an ImageItem. I'm sorry that I don't know enough about this to know why this approach might be chosen.

OTOH, I know that the API is not the only way to update an image in an ImageItem. The following answer is bound to a linked spreadsheet (though obviously there are several methods that one can use to access the Form) and uses `setImage()` to update the image content.

It is VERY important to understand that the argument for `setImage` is a `BlobSource`. So the image uri is `fetch` and converted to a blob.

- [setImage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/image-item#setimageimage)

---

```
function updateImage() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1")

  // get the linked form
  var url = sheet.getFormUrl();
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the url = "+url)
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(url)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: form name = "+form.getTitle()+", description"+form.getDescription())
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: form id = "+form.getId()) 

  // Gets the list of items in the form.
  var items = form.getItems();

  // Gets the type for each item and logs them to the console.
  var types = items.map((item) => item.getType().name());
  // Logger.log(types)

  // Logger.log("DEBUG: number of items = "+items.length)
  // for information, loop though the images
  for (var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
  var item = items[i]
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: i="+i+", type ="+item.getType()+", name = "+item.getTitle()+", id = "+item.getId())
  }

  // convert the new image to a blob
  var newImage = "https://daily.jstor.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/standardizedtests.jpg"
  var img = (UrlFetchApp.fetch(newImage));
  var blob = img.getBlob();

  // set the image
  var imageQn = items[1].asImageItem()
  imageQn.setImage(blob)

}
```

---

**SAMPLE - Before**

[image: sample]

---

**SAMPLE - After**

[image: after]